# Как создать вот такие березовые столбцы на левом сайдбаре в моем примере?

Tags: css, вёрстка

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#one {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #0587A4;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#two {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #0587A4;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#three {
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.first {
  background-color: #CECECE;
}
.second {
  width: 150px;
}
.third {
  background-color: #CECECE;
}
.fourth {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #0587A4;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="one">
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="two">
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="three">
    <td class="first">


    </td>
    <td class="second"></td>
    <td class="third"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Простите, а кто сейчас сайт таблицей делает?

Comment: @Yuri а что это, запрещено законом?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, надо запретить, это убивает мои нервы :)

Comment: @Andrew_Romanuk А скажите тут задача просто фон с такими "островками" сплошного цвета сделать и всё?

Comment: @Andrew_Romanuk И ещё вопрос: "берёзовый" у вас означает "полосатый"? Что именно вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Березовый - это другой цвет на картинке выше ( не серый ). Ну, желательно конечно было бы создать с помощью <tr> и <td>. Можете создать с помощью <tr> и <td>, я выберу ваш ответ тогда лучшим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не верстайте таблицами, на улице уже 2017й, не 2000й. Но если Решились на таблицы, то вот ответ на ваш вопрос.

```css
table
{
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#one
{
    height:150px;
    background-color: #0587A4;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
#two
{
    height:50px;
    background-color: #0587A4;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
#three
{
    height:450px;
    border:1px solid #000000;  
}
.first
{
    background-color: #CECECE;
}
.second
{
    width:150px;
}
.third
{
    background-color: #CECECE;
}
.fourth
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #0587A4;
}

/* Added this css code */

.banner{
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #0587A4;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charsеt=utf-8"> 
        <title>Web page</title> 

    </head> 
    <body> 

        <table>
            <tr id="one">
                <td colspan="3" >

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="two">
                <td colspan="3" >

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="three">
                <td class="first" >

                    <!--         Added this blocks           -->

                    <div class="banner"></div>
                    <div class="banner"></div>
                    <div class="banner"></div>

                </td>
                <td class="second" ></td>
                <td class="third" >

                    <!--         Added this blocks           -->

                    <div class="banner"></div>
                    <div class="banner"></div>
                    <div class="banner"></div>

                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>


    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 3):

А я всё же предложу вариант без таблицы :)

```css
body {background-color: #cecece;}
.header {
  width:100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #187e83;
}
.menu {
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #187e83;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.body {display: flex;}
.body__left-menu {width: 120px; margin-top: 10px;}
.body__main {
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}
.body__right-menu {width: 120px; margin-top: 10px;}
.body__menu-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 120px;
  background-color: #187e83;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.footer{
  width: calc(100% - 260px);
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="menu">
</div>
<div class="body">
  <div class="body__left-menu">
    <div class="body__menu-block"></div>
    <div class="body__menu-block"></div>
    <div class="body__menu-block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="body__main"></div>
  <div class="body__right-menu">
    <div class="body__menu-block"></div>
    <div class="body__menu-block"></div>
    <div class="body__menu-block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас задача просто создать полосатый блок со сплошными цветами, то здесь можно воспользоваться линейным градиентом. В задаче *для демонстрации* применил целых 3.

Для разметки рекомендую использовать flexbox. В данном примере многие измерения выражены в единицам экрана (`vw` и `vh`), а также в единицах градиента используются проценты. Но это необязательно и остаётся полностью на усмотрение тех, кто воспользуется данным примером, творчески адаптируя его под себя.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #cecece;
}

.first-row {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 20vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0587A4 80%, transparent 80%, transparent 85%, #0587A4 85%); 
}

.second-row {
  display: flex;
  height: 60vh;
}

.brick-column {
  width: 20vw;
  margin: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0587A4 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 30%, #0587A4 30%, #0587A4 55%, transparent 55%, transparent 60%, #0587A4 60%, #0587A4 85%, transparent 85%);
}

.center-column {
  width: 60vw;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 90%, transparent 90%, transparent 95%, #fff 95%);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="first-row">
  </div>
  
  <div class="second-row">
    <div class="brick-column">
    </div>
    <div class="center-column">
    </div>
    <div class="brick-column">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```